# What is the natural prey for headcrabs?

Tags: video-games, half-life, evolution

Headcrabs perfectly fit on human heads. But they must have evolved to that point on their home world (which is not Xen, btw.) without humans. How did their food chain look like before they came (escaped from the Combine, really) to Earth?

Comment: maybe they did not evolve, but were designed as biological weapons?

Comment: What do you mean that Headcrabs aren't from Xen.  Also, headcrabs fit the heads of the Combine.

Comment: @vsz: The Combine use them as biological weapons, but I would assume they evolved naturally on their previous home world.

Comment: @BluFire: The Nihilanth flew with his civilisation to Xen to escape the Combine.

Comment: Well then that means that the Food Chain would be impossible to answer without knowing the Combine Homeworld.  As i said headcrabs probably was assimilating the Combine before humans.  In the Half-life 2 series, there was a picture with the head anatomy of Humans and Combines showing that their head size were similar.

Comment: @BluFire: Good point. That would depend on how long the Nihilanth was at war with the Combine.

Comment: @Blue the combine are not a species. I don't know what picture you're referring to, but it was probably of an augmented human.

Answer (score 7):

As vsz suggests in the comments, it's always been my assumption (and nothing in the series openly contradicts this) that headcrabs, and possibly other creatures we see in the series, are engineered bioweapons and not naturally evolved at all. It's unlikely that they were designed **specifically** to attack humans, but they do seem to adapt to humans-as-prey pretty easily.

Comment: Vortigaunts have human-sized heads.

Comment: @OrangeDog But we have never seen a vort being attacked by a head crab.

Comment: @bitmask so what?

Comment: @Why don't they attack vorts if that is their "natural" prey?